# XmlHttpRequest Cannot Load Error with youtube video link

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Im getting the following error

"jlEYu--6T14?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&playlist=jlEYu--6T14:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://r3---sn-a5m7zu7e.googlevideo.com/videogoodput?id=o-AOVPXHeRRmIiRNUb…a&cms_redirect=yes&ipbits=0&mm=34&mn=sn-a5m7zu7e&ms=ltu&mt=1460384654&mv=m. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

with the following code used to play a video from youtube

```
 <iframe id="player" width="800" height="480"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jlEYu--6T14?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&loop=1&playlist=jlEYu--6T14"
                    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<script>
                @*To mute the video*@
    @*To load the youtube player api asynchronously*@
                var tag = document.createElement('script');
                tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


                var player;
                var player;
                function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                    player = new YT.Player('player', {
                        //height: '390',
                        //width: '640',
                        //videoId: 'jlEYu--6T14',
                        events: {
                            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                            //'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    });
                }

                function onPlayerReady(event) {
                    event.target.setVolume(0);
                    event.target.playVideo();
                    //player.mute();
                }
            </script>
```

What could be causing this ? How do i solve it?

Comment: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTTP_access_control)